# Show that process is a Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)_{t \ge 0}$ be a Brownian Motion. Define the process $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ by $X_t := e^{-t} B_{e^{2t}}$. Now I am supposed to show that
$M_t := X_t - X_0 + \int_0^t X_s \, ds$ defines a Brownian Motion.

I tried to show that $E[M_t M_s] = t \wedge s$ but I failed.

I already know that $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is a stationary process with normal distributed random variables. So is it easier to "just" verify the definition of a Brownian motion in this case? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I'm not severely miscalculating $\langle X \rangle_t = 1$ so that $\langle M \rangle_t = \langle X \rangle_t = 1$ for all $t \geq 0$. In particular, since if $W$ is a Brownian motion $\langle W \rangle_t = t$, $M$ is not a Brownian motion.

Comment: Ok, that might be the reason I could not verify $E[MtMs]=t \wedge s$. I assume that $< . > _t $ is the sharp bracket, but we did not cover this in the lecture yet hence I don't want to use this. Could it be true that $M_t$ is a martingale? So maybe just the task is just wrong.

Comment: $M_t$ isn't a martingale. (It's in fact not even a local martingale since its semimartingale decomposition has non-zero finite variation part. If you know about semimartingale decompositions then this is another way to see that $M_t$ is not a Brownian motion.)

Comment: @nobody : Ok thank you. Is there a way to show that $M_t$ is not a Brownian motion without tools such as the sharp bracket? I tried to do this with the definition f.e. show that the increments are not normal distributed via the characteristic function, but I struggled with the integral part of $M_t$  (like I did, when i tried to calculate $ E[MtMs]$.

Comment: It suffices to show that $\mathbb{E}(M_t^2) \neq t$ ...

Comment: Ok. I tried to verify this, but I am not sure if my calculations are correct. I get $E[X_t \int_0^t X_s ds] = 1- e^{-t}$, $E[X_0 \int_0^t X_s ds] = 1- e^{-t}$ and $E[\int_0^t X_s ds \int_0^t X_s ds] = t^2$. Is this ok? And if not any help/hint on how to calculate these means is appreciated!

Comment: @saz I now calculated $E[M_t^2] = 2t$. Can anyone check if this is true?

Comment: @Diamir The result is correct, see my answer below for one possible approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was already pointed out in the above comments, $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is not a Brownian motion. To prove it suffices to show that $$\mathbb{E}(M_t^2) \neq t.$$

Clearly,

$$\mathbb{E}(X_t X_s) = e^{-(t+s)} \mathbb{E}(B_{e^{2t}} B_{e^{2s}}) = e^{-(t+s)} \min\{e^{2s},e^{2t}\} \tag{1}$$

and

$$\mathbb{E}((M_t+X_0)^2) = \mathbb{E}(X_t^2) + 2 \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t X_t X_s \, ds \right) + \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t \int_0^t X_s X_r \, ds \, dr \right). \tag{2}$$

We have already calculated the first term on the right-hand side. Using $(1)$ we find

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t X_s X_t \, ds \right) &= e^{-t} \int_0^t e^s \, ds = e^{-t} (e^t-1) = 1-e^{-t}. \end{align*}$$

Similarly,

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t \int_0^t X_r X_s \, ds \, dr \right) &= 2 \int_0^t \int_0^r \mathbb{E}(X_s X_r) \, ds \, dr \\ &= 2 \int_0^t e^{-r} \int_0^r e^{s} \, ds \, dr \\ &= 2 \int_0^t e^{-r} (e^r-1) \, dr \\ &= 2t+2(e^{-t}-1). \end{align*}$$

Combining all the calculations, we conclude

$$\mathbb{E}((M_t+X_0)^2) = 1 + 2 (1-e^{-t}) + 2t+2(e^{-t}-1) = 1+2t$$

implying

$$\mathbb{E}(M_t^2) = 2t.$$